# License checkout failed while using lsqcurvefit

Tags: matlab, licensing

I'm working with the lsqcurvefit function in matlab
But when I run it I get an error 'license checkout failed'
Does anyone have any idea what's causing this?
The error message is as below.

```
License checkout failed.
License Manager Error -18
Make sure the license file on the MATLAB client matches the license file of the         license server and that the license server has been
started properly.

Troubleshoot this issue by visiting:
http://www.mathworks.com/support/lme/R2011b/18

Diagnostic Information:
Feature: Optimization_Toolbox
License path:
C:\Users\yjan020\AppData\Roaming\MathWorks\MATLAB\R2011b_licenses;C:\Matlab\R2011b        \CK\licenses\license.dat;C:\Matlab\R2011b\CK\licenses\network.lic
FLEXnet Licensing error: -18,147.

Error in lsq (line 7)
x = lsqcurvefit(@fun,x0,xdata,ydata); 
>> lsqcurvefit(@fun,x0,xdata,ydata)
```

Comment: It sounds like either you don't have that toolbox installed or are using the wrong license file or are out of licenses for that toolbox. What is the output of the `ver` command?

Answer (score 0):

Your license has expired. You must renew Matlab.